# JQuery find and delete clicked id number in a value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to delete the clicked id number in a input value using jQuery. I need help here, I'm confused about how I should follow that path to delete clicked id in a input value.

I'll try to tell you simply what I want to do.

Please check this **[DEMO](https://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/BVmRLq)** from codepen.io. In this demo you can see there are 4 box 4 mini black div on there. Each black div has its own id. When you click first black div `<div class="del" id="1">x</div>` then value of input 1 must be delete from this input value `<input type="text" id="value" value="1,2,3,4">` like this: `<input type="text" id="value" value="2,3,4">` with comma (`,`). How can i do that, anyone can help me in this regard please ?

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="global_box">
    <div class="item_box" id="id1"><div class="del" id="1">x</div></div>
    <div class="item_box" id="id2"><div class="del" id="2">x</div></div>
    <div class="item_box" id="id3"><div class="del" id="3">x</div></div>
    <div class="item_box" id="id4"><div class="del" id="4">x</div></div>
    <div class="values"><input type="text" id="value" value="1,2,3,4"></div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("body").on("click", ".del", function(){
       // Wanted to delete id
       var ID = $(this).attr("id");

   });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("body").on("click", ".del", function(){
       // Wanted to delete id
       var ID = $(this).attr("id");
       var input = $('#value');
           input.val(function(_, value){
       return value.split(',').filter(function(val){ // split the value
         return val !== ID; // filter to return other values
       }).join(','); // join them to create a new string.
    });
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="global_box">
    <div class="item_box" id="id1"><div class="del" id="1">x</div></div>
    <div class="item_box" id="id2"><div class="del" id="2">x</div></div>
    <div class="item_box" id="id3"><div class="del" id="3">x</div></div>
    <div class="item_box" id="id4"><div class="del" id="4">x</div></div>
    <div class="values"><input type="text" id="value" value="1,2,3,4"></div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: value.split is not a function

Comment: @Azzo correct that should be the second argument. Just updated the answer.

Comment: @Azzo You need to double check that `$('value')` has an actual valid value if thats the case.

Comment: @jai your answer removing all comma, but it should delete just after the clicked number comma like `1,2,3,4` to `2,3,4` .....

Comment: @Azzo my bad i had to join it again with a comma. updated it again.

Answer (score 1):

Currently you're selecting on the body element, you want to select the del element. After that you can just get the ID value, replace with empty string, then use Regex to replace the commas at the beginning and end. Code below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".del").on("click", function(){
       // Wanted to delete id
     var newValue =  $("#value").val().replace($(this).attr("id"), "");
     $("#value").val( newValue.replace(/^,/, "").replace(/,$/, "") );
   });
});
```

Comment: please read a question i am not asking your answer i am asking how to delete clicked id number in a input value.

Comment: Oh whoops, thought you were trying to delete the element, I'll update my answer